# Get Cron Expression from Trigger

Tags: quartz.net

How can I get the CronExpression (string) from a trigger?

I see the expression in the DB but I am not sure how to retrieve it via the provided API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try to cast the `ITrigger` instance to an `ICronTrigger` and call the `CronExpressionString` property.

```
if(trigger is ICronTrigger cronTrigger)
{
    return cronTrigger.CronExpressionString;
}
```